# When is necessary and sufficient for the second run of `git merge` stop reporting any conflict?

Tags: git

When I run

```
git merge master
```

i am merging the master branch into my current branch.

When a merge reports any conflicts, I resolve the conflicts by editing the conflicts in the files reported to have the conflicts, and then making a commit.

Then i want to assure myself that I have resolved all the conflicts, by running the merge command again, to see if it still reports any conflict. I haven't seen a case where the second run of the merge command still report conflict.
But it looks to me that the new commit on my feature branch from resolving merge conflict very much likely has conflicts with the master branch, when comparing the changed conflict areas with their original contents.

So what changes to the files with conflicts are necessary and sufficient to make the second run of the merge command not report any conflict?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are saying "git merge a-branch" and "a-branch" is exactly the same branch you asked to merge before and there is no new revision on it, it will never fail because, regardless of the content of files on that revision, after you have finished merging (and committing) for the first time, a-branch (that revision at the tip) is already part of the history of your current branch and so git kind of thinks "there's nothing to merge" (even if all files were modified on your current branch).

Comment: Thanks. "after you have finished merging (and committing) for the first time, a-branch (that revision at the tip) is already part of the history of your current branch". When a branch (eg. a-branch in your post, or master in my post) is already part of the history of my current branch, can it still evolve? For example, can I check it out and then pull from a remote repository to update it? Can i check it out, work on it, and create a new commit?

Comment: Sure, man.... merging is part of life and branches can be merged in pretty crazy ways.So, you merge branchA into branchB, you can continue developing on top of both branches and then ask branchA to be merged into branchB again (or the other way around... it makes basically no difference in the end result).

Comment: "after you have finished merging (and committing) for the first time, a-branch (that revision at the tip) is already part of the history of your current branch and so git kind of thinks "there's nothing to merge" (even if all files were modified on your current branch)." Do you mean that there is always no conflict reported by running the merge command for the second time, after i create a commit following a merge attempt?

Comment: Following a merge attempt which reports conflict, will creating a new commit with any change (even without making any change to resolve any existing conflict)  make git think "there is nothing to merge", and therefore not report any conflict?

Comment: It's not that simple because the forking point (which is where the diff starts to be analyzed) will be the last revision from the merged branch and so git will say "nothing to merge from that other branch". What you _could_ do is cherry-pick/rebase the changes from the "wrongly" merged branch on a separate branch (say, a cloned branch) and merge it again so that git sees no relation with the original wrongly-merged branch. Not elegant but could work. I personally don't like these approaches. I'd go back in history and redo the whole thing so that it's "right". One of the beauties of using git.

Comment: Thanks. The problem in my comments is not that the merged branch is a wrong branch to be merged. My comments are asking the following question. When a merge command reports any conflict, do I need to make any change in the conflict areas followed up by creating a new commit, in order to make the second run of the merge command not report any conflict? If yes, what kind of changes?

Comment: AFAIK, nothing will ever happen (that you merge branch branchA, fix all conflicts, commit, merge branchA again). You might have done everything the wrong way to solve conflicts. You might have left the files as they were on your current branch before the merge, it doesn't matter. To git, branchA (**the revision** it is currently pointing to) has already been merged into your current branch  (in other words, **that revision** is already part of the history of the current branch) and so if you ask for a second merge of that revision git will simply discard the operation.

Comment: Think about it: You are asking git to merge a revision that is **already** part of the history of the branch you are working on. What is the point?

Answer (score 1):

After a merge there are no conflicts, even if it seems like there might be.

consider the branch before and after the merge. It might look something like this:

master:

```
 A -> B -> C
```

branch:

```
 A -> B -> D
```

So the branched diverged, and that's why you need to manually resolve the conflicts. After the merge you might see something like this:

branch:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

Where `E` is the new post-merge commit. Now, although when looking at the code it looks like there are conflict, in reality git now knows in what order the changes were meant to happen. So it doesn't see the so-called conflicts as conflicts at all, just as a normal evolution of the code.

---

I also want to note that to my experience you would normally never merge the master branch to another branch, but always branch *from* master and merge back to it when the branch development is done.

Following this protocol might save you a lot of manual merges